# Why NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener does not be resolved

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have the following in build.gradle but I got `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` not resolved in the java code. Any idea please... How to make it resolved and go to another activity or any other action when any item of the navigation drawer is clicked.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.welcome.madrasti"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }


}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.+'

    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation group: 'com.pubnub', name: 'pubnub-gson', version: '4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

}
```

Comment: Have you refreshed your build.gradle after adding support:design library? I can't see any reason you would not get `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` interface resolved unless this library is not actually donwloaded

Comment: I refreshed it ....